# Como obter os valores de uma textBox?

Tags: c#, textbox

Eu criei um exemplo pra vocês verem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é o seguinte. Eu to tentando pega o valor contido na `TextBox` convertendo pra um tipo string pra poder usar na `MessageBox`, más ele fica exibindo

> *System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: oi*

eu queria saber o jeito correto pra captura o valor da textBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A propriedade correta do [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) é [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a19tt6sk(v=vs.110).aspx) para recuperar ou definir um texto nesse *controle*:

*Recuperar:*

```
string grava = textBox1.Text;
```

*Definir:*

```
textBox1.Text = "Novo Texto";
```

***Referencias:***

- [Classe TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Propriedade TextBox.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a19tt6sk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -3):

O `TextBox` é do tipo `Text`. Então sempre que você for usar um `TextBox`, `Label` ou `ComboBox`, no final tem que colocar seu tipo, que neste caso é `.Text`

Tente assim:

```
var gravar = NOMEDATEXTBOX.Text;

MessageBox.Show(gravar, "Test");
```

Comment: Não existe um tipo `Text`. Text é o nome da propriedade apenas.