# A respeito do Windows.Forms do C#

Tags: c#

estou em um projeto de replicação de banco de dados e estou passando por um problema.

Ao referenciar um campo que vem de um textBox ele está trazendo toda a informação da textBox e nao apenas o valor que inseri dentro dela. Esse é meu código:

```
string conexao = "Server=localhost;port=5432;User Id="+db.Usuario.ToString()+";Password="+db.Senha.ToString() + ";Database="+db.Banco.ToString();
```

Segue imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso de forma que apenas o texto dentro da textbox apareça?
Desde ja agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: tentou usar `.Text`? me parece que está lendo o próprio textbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como obter os valores de uma textBox?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174405/como-obter-os-valores-de-uma-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa usar a propriedade `Text` para obter o valor informado no TextBox. Usando o método `ToString()`, a menos que ele tenha sido implementado de forma diferente no objeto, você sempre obterá o nome completo do tipo.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```c#
string conexao = "Server=localhost;port=5432"
                + ";User Id=" + db.Usuario.Text
                + ";Password=" + db.Senha.Text 
                + ";Database=" + db.Banco.Text;
```

Comment: Então, eu já havia tentado dessa forma mas o .Text fica em vermelho.
https://prnt.sc/q8wo19

Comment: Poste a parte referente ao arquivo *.Designer.cs* para sabermos do que se trata a sua propriedade **db**

Comment: Desculpe, eu só vi a imagem agora. Post o código (ou parte dele) da classe *Database*

Comment: MEUS QUERIDOS, MUITO OBRIGADO A AJUDA. Achei meu erro.

Comment: Na parte em que recebo os dados, eu estava tratando da forma errada.
private void senhaOrigem_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bancoOrigem.Senha = senhaOrigem.Text;
        }

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do amigo acima estava correta. Eu me perdi na hora de capturar as informações.

```
private void UsuarioDestino_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bancoDestino.Usuario = sender.ToString();
    }
```

Mas a forma correta é como o amigo falou:

```
private void UsuarioDestino_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bancoDestino.Usuario = UsuarioDestino.Text;
    }
```

Obrigado a ajuda de todos.